# Change Project Explorer tree view font size in Eclipse Oxygen

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-plugin, font-size

I am using Eclipse Version: Oxygen.1a Release (4.7.1a) and I want to enlarge the Project Explorer tree view font size because I have some sight issues and thus I searched many places to enlarge the project tree view font size.

[image]

I only founded the font change in project explorer tree view for older eclipse versions releases which are older or equal to Eclipse Luna version.

For the information I would like to say that this Oxygen version release is latest in Eclipse IDE.

Comment: https://codeyarns.com/2014/11/03/how-to-set-font-and-font-size-of-eclipse-ui/

Answer (score 29, accepted):

In Eclipse the font-sizes of the UI elements can be adjusted in the following preferences values:

**Increase java editor font size**

```
Window Menu -> Preferences -> General > Appearance > Color and Fonts > Java > Java Editor Text Font > Edit & Apply
```

**Increase console output font size**

```
Window Menu -> Preferences -> General > Appearance > Color and Fonts > Debug > Console font > Edit & Apply
```

**Increase XML bean file font size**

```
Window Menu -> Preferences -> General > Appearance > Color and Fonts > Basic > Text Font > Edit & Apply
```

**Increase dialog view font size**

```
Window Menu -> Preferences -> General > Appearance > Color and Fonts > Basic > Dialog Font > Edit & Apply
```

**Increase project explorer tree view font size**

[image]

If using Windows 7 or higher architecture, then reach to the Eclipse home directory, go inside of `eclipse\plugins\org.eclipse.ui.themes_X.X.X.vXXXXXXXX-XXXX\css` directory,
find two css files which are `"e4_default_gtk.css"` and `"e4_default_win.css"`, open and add below said CSS script part in tail of above two files, save those and close accordingly:

```
.MPart Tree {
    font-family: Consolas;
    font-size: 14;
}
```

If Eclipse is opened, restart, it all worked for me on Eclipse oxygen.1a release version, and hope on other OS type, you have to edit the same `e4_default_gtk.css` and other `e4_default_os-type.css`.

Comment: The trick for the project explorer tree doesn't work in Oxygen and Photon on Windows 10.

Comment: Moreover, I checked with procmon, Eclipse not using these .css files at all. I mean none from that directory.

Comment: hi all, this all is about Eclipse Oxygen version, so in Windows 7, 8.1 & 10 it is working fine.

Comment: Just checked Oxygen on Windows 10. It doesn't work. On Windows the SWT uses a standard Windows tree control, nothing's fancy. The font size depends only on Windows settings, nothing in Eclipse changes it.

Comment: With Oxy-3a on Mac, all tree elements are bigger now except for the one changed (using git of course), which stay old size. This is even when I change `e4_basestyle.css`  too.

Comment: It doesn't work!! Just now checked in Neon.3 Release (4.6.3) in MacOS :(

Comment: I am able to change the font in the Package Explorer in Eclipse 2019-12 on Windows 10 by adding a style for Tree to e4_basestyle.css like: Tree {
  font-size: 9px; 
  font: Consolas;  
}

Answer (score 66):

There is now (Eclipse 4.17, July 2020) an [official setting](https://www.eclipse.org/eclipse/news/4.17/platform.php#ViewsAndDialogs):

> The font used for tree and table views can now be customized with a font preference. This preference is called "Tree and Table font for views" and can be found in Window > Preferences > General > Appearance > Colors and Fonts under the "View and Editor Folders" category.

[image: https://www.eclipse.org/eclipse/news/4.17/images/adjustable-view-font-preference.png]

> The Project Explorer is an example of a view that gets affected by this font preference.

[image: https://www.eclipse.org/eclipse/news/4.17/images/adjustable-view-font.png]

Answer (score 11):

I have been searching this for every version of Eclipse and finally I got something which helped me to increase the font size and font type of of the project explorer.

1.go to below path on your local environment

**.p2 -> pool -> plugins -> org.eclipse.ui.themes_(version) -> css -> e4_basestyle**

2.paste below lines at the end of the file.

```
Tree {
     font-size: 14px; /* <-- Desired font size */
     font: Consolas;  /* <-- Font you want to have */
}
```

3. Restart the eclipse
4. You will get the new defined size and font in your project explorer of eclipse.

**NOTE : I tried this on latest version of the eclipse on windows 10 and it worked for me. I did not tried on the previous version.**

Comment: I needed to apply this to **e4-dark_mac.css** because I'm using the dark theme and it worked.

Comment: I modified e4-dark_globalstyle.css .. beginning to wonder if it matters what CSS file it goes into. I added to that file and worked after restart.

Answer (score 8):

I'm using eclipse-neon on Ubuntu on Windows-10. The graphical interface is not supported by Microsoft at this time, but I have been using Eclipse Neon and it works decently enough. I added the following to the end of one file:  eclipse/plugins/org.eclipse.ui.themes_1.1.300.v20161107-1827/css/e4_default_gtk.css:

```
.MPart Tree {
font-family: Sans Regular;
font-size: 8;
}
```

My intent was to make the font smaller, and it worked successfully.

Comment: I'm using eclipse 2018-09 on openSUSE and Gnome. This mostly works, but uncommitted resources in EGit still use the larger font. I could change this through the eclipse preferences, but it would be better to sort this out in the CSS as well. I'll look into this a bit more when I have time.....

Answer (score 5):

Go to Preferences -> (search for) Fonts -> View and Editor Folders -> (select the last option) Tree and Table font for views -> Edit (left hand side) -> and change the font size.

Answer (score 3):

Thanks for the help. In my case, I use the Dark [Mac OS X] theme in Eclipse Photon on Windows 7, so the file I had to alter was `e4-dark_mac.css` in  `eclipse\plugins\org.eclipse.ui.themes_X.X.X.vXXXXXXXX-XXXX\css`. Also the `.MPart Tree` was not in the file so I had to add it as opposed to editing it. I added right under another `.Mpart` entry so my file looked like below.

```
...

.MpartStack, .Mpart {
    font-family: '#org-eclipse-ui-workbench-TAB_TEXT_FONT';
}

.Mpart Tree {
    font-size: 12;
}

...
```

Comment: This worked for me on Mac OS 10.15, using the path @Cristiano mentioned in his answer above, for Eclipse 2020-03 (4.15.0).

Answer (score 3):

[Ankit Fulzele's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56030531/11028863) helped me with minor adjustments.

I use Dark Theme on Mac and the following worked for me for Eclipse 2019-06:

Add the following lines to ~/.p2/pool/plugins/org.eclipse.ui.themes_{version}/css/**dark**/e4-dark_basestyle.css

```
Tree {
        font-family: '#org-eclipse-ui-workbench-TAB_TEXT_FONT';
}
```

Instead of setting a fixed font, this will pin it to whatever the "Preferences -> General -> Appearance -> Colors and Fonts -> View and Editor Folders -> Part title font" is configured to.

Note: It would make more sense to pin this to another setting, e.g. to "Preferences -> General -> Appearance -> Colors and Fonts -> Basic -> Text Font", but couldn't find the CSS reference for it.

Note: This update will change not only the "Project Explorer" tab, but others as well.

Answer (score 2):

Answer from [Al Breight](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51295539/5133304) worked perfectly on Oxygen.3a Release (4.7.3a), Ubuntu 18.04. @pkeller comment (Oct 16 at 14:05) confirmed and solved editing 'Git Uncommited Change Font' size option in *Window->Preferences->General->Appearance->Colors and Fonts*:

[image]

Comment: This is only for the "uncommitted" stuff.

Comment: Yes, that was the problem that pkeller marked on his comment

Answer (score 2):

In my case using a MacBook 13", I had to edit the following file `/Users/myuser/.p2/pool/plugins/org.eclipse.ui.themes_1.2.800.v20191030-0746/css/e4-dark_mac1013.css`

Then I searched for this existing item and added the `font-size` and `font-size-adjust`. Doing that prevents the tree line to be cropped:

```
CTabFolder Tree, CTabFolder Canvas {
    background-color: #2F2F2F;
    color: #CCC;
    font-size-adjust: none;
    font-size: 14px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks so much!  I can finally see the Eclipse Project Explorer clearly!
I was able to change the project explorer tree font size by making the css file addition shown above in Windows 7 with Eclipse 2018-9 (4.9.0).

The specific folder location I found was at:

```
C:\Users\myUserName\.p2\pool\plugins\org.eclipse.ui.themes_1.2.200.v20180828-1350\css
```

Apparently, from my investigation of solving this problem the specific folder location varies based on different factors like Eclipse Version and OS.
So I searched on the css file names to find the latest folder.

I had 7 eclipse themes folders on my workstation, I used the most recent one, corresponding to the specific install/update of Eclipse being currently used.

Answer (score 0):

I'm using Eclipse 2018-09 and could't found .css file similar gtk at Eclipe directory.
But I discover custom css menu on Jeeyul's theme(plugin for Eclipse Color UI).
Just typing css style above comments. And apply and close.
In the end, change UI style.

Answer (score 0):

ECLIPSE FONT CHANGE - Change below to 2 css files.

> eclipse/plugins/org.eclipse.ui.themes_x.x.x.vxxxxx/css/e4_basesetyle.css
>   eclipse/plugins/org.eclipse.ui.themes_x.x.x.vxxxxx/css/dark/e4-dark_globalstyle.css

```
#org-eclipse-jdt-ui-PackageExplorer Tree,
#org-eclipse-ui-navigator-ProjectExplorer Tree {
    font-size: 10px; /* <-- Desired font size */
    font: Consolas;  /* <-- Font you want to have */
}
```

and change preference -> General > Appearance > Colors and Fonts > Basic > Text Font : Consolas 12px

Comment: Could you mention on what Eclipse version, you have done this tweak, so it will be easier for the arrivers.

Answer (score 0):

To increase font size of eclipse project explorer window for eclipse 2020-06.

First check the theme, you are using in the eclipse from preferences.Increase the value of below property for that theme. For example, if you are using **light** theme.

In file:
/Applications/Eclipse.app/Contents/Eclipse/plugins/org.eclipse.ui.themes_1.2.1000.v20200528-1125/css/**light**/e4-light_partstyle.css,

Add property if missing or if it is already present, just increase value of font size.

```
.MPart Tree {
    font-size: 13;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Eclipse Project/Package explorer, Outline window are using OS default font for labels.
For Win 7+ go to *Control Panel\Appearance and Personalization\Personalization* click *'Window Color'* to start ***'Window Color and Appearance'*** dialog.
Increase ***'Message Box'*** font.
As a bonus you'll have other programs pop-ups more user friendly most likely you are using large display if you bother with eclipse project explorer font.

[image]

Eclipse restart required

Answer (score 0):

1. The changes to the ".css" files don't work, if you have disabled "theming", during your efforts to alter the font size ("Settings.General.Appearance.Enalbe theming (requires restart)" (I mean, I found during my efforts :)
2. To cover all bases and "themes_*versions*", rather than hit and miss the right css file, change all ".css" files (find eclipse/plugins -name '*.css') and add "* { font-size:7; }" at the end of every file. Specify your size, and font-family as well if you like.

Works on: Version: 2019-09 R (4.13.0) / Build id: 20190917-1200

Answer (score 0):

I'm using eclipse 2019-06 (4.12.0) version and I didn't find this path (`eclipse\plugins\org.eclipse.ui.themes_X.X.X.vXXXXXXXX-XXXX\css`), instead I went to the path shown in the below pic with selected folders named `org.eclipse.ui.themes_1.2.600.v20190513-0458` and `org.eclipse.ui.themes_1.2.1400.v20210315-1604`
[image]

Under `themes_1.2.600.v20190513-0458` folder, go into `css` folder

[image: themes_1.2.600.v20190513-0458]

Now you can change the selected css files selected here in the below pic.
[image]

Add the property highlighted in the below pic for both the css files, save the files, restart eclipse and viola we are done with the font change.

Note: You can either change to small font or big font depending on your choice by changing the font size number.

```
.MPart Tree {
    font-size: 14;
}
```

[image]

Before Change:

[image]

After Change:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

In Eclipse (2023-12 R) the font-sizes of the Project Explorer tree view can be adjusted in the following preferences values:

Window Menu -> Preferences -> General > Appearance > Color and Fonts > View and Editor Folders > Tree and Table font for views

[image]