# Change content assist font size only

Tags: css, eclipse

For a while now I am looking for a solution to increase selected components font sizes in Eclipse IDE. This is due to the fact, that this IDE is completely unusable on high DPI monitor (unless one is a hawk).

In this answer ( [Change Project Explorer tree view font size in Eclipse Oxygen](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47731327/change-project-explorer-tree-view-font-size-in-eclipse-oxygen) ) I have found how to increase the font size of the project explorer and the outline:

```
.MPart Tree {
    font-family: Consolas;
    font-size: 14;
}
```

[image]

Now I am looking for a way to increase the font of context assist. This simple solution wont do:

```
* {
    font-size: 14;
    font-family: Hack;
}
```

It does increase all possible fonts in the editor, but it also forces this font size everywhere. For example, If I change the font of the editor (by doing `ctrl -` or `ctrl shift +`), then click away somewhere, the editor font will detrimentally go back to the set font in the css file. I believe this is somehow bugged. So the only way for me now is to increase the content assist font only. Is there a css tag for that? How to do this?

Answer (score 0):

The Eclipse CSS Spy say "Shell Table" for change the content assist

Try follow, it works fine for me.

```
Shell Table {    
    font-family: Consolas;
    font-size: 14px;    
}
```

[Eclipse CSS Spy](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NqBSr.png)