# How to change Eclipse RCP application Tree and Table font

Tags: eclipse-rcp

I am running Eclipse version 4.22. I can change the font size of Project Explorer by selecting Window->Preferences->General->Appearance->Colors and Fonts and then selecting a font size for **Tree and Table font for views**.

I have an Eclipse RCP application built with 4.22, but I cannot do the same thing within my application. Changing the font size for **Tree and Table font for views** has no effect. How do you change the Tree and Table font size for RCP applications?

Comment: For a 3.x compatability mode RCP that is all done using the CSS in the `org.eclipse.ui.themes` plug-in. You will have to look at the CSS and work out how to get it to apply to your controls.

Comment: Just testing here with the current Eclipse 2022-09 (4.25) the "Tree and Table font for views" setting just works for some simple test views. How exactly are you creating the tree/table? Are these tree/tables in a view or editor?

Comment: @greg-449 In looking at the code (I inherited this application), it looks like it is adding several predefined views:
addView(IPageLayout.ID_PROJECT_EXPLORER),
addView(IPageLayout.ID_PROBLEM_VIEW),
addView(IPageLayout.ID_TASK_LIST),
addView(IPageLayout.ID_PROGRESS_VIEW).
If I change the Part title font, it changes the title of all these. But unable to change the body font of these.

Comment: @greg-449 I tried modifying the 28 .css files within the /plugins/org.eclipse.ui.themes*/css directory of my installed application, adding Tree { font-size: 18px } to the end of each (as per this link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47731327/change-project-explorer-tree-view-font-size-in-eclipse-oxygen) but had no effect when I restarted my application.

Comment: I think the `.MPartStack Tree, .MPartStack Table` style in `common/e4_globalstyle.css` is what sets the style for tree/table in views.

Comment: @greg-449 Thank you for looking into this. Unfortunately, those changes are not having any effect.